# Apple's Swift-Binding of Data Types

Tags: swift, data-binding, programming-languages

I have a fairly straightforward question about the binding of data types in the Swift programming language. I was surprised not to find any concrete information on the subject through my searches so I believe it would be best to bring my question to here for an in-depth answer:

- How are data types bound in Apple's Swift programming language?
- Are data types bound to variables and parameters at compile-time?
- Are they bound to a run-time or a combination of the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift binds data types at compile time.  If you are programming Swift using Xcode, you can find the type of any variable in your code by <kbd>Option</kbd>-clicking on that variable.

Here is an excerpt from 
[The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) (emphasis mine):

> Swift is a type-safe language. A type safe language encourages you to
>   be clear about the types of values your code can work with. If part of
>   your code expects a String, you can’t pass it an Int by mistake.
>
> Because Swift is type safe, **it performs type checks when compiling
>   your code** and flags any mismatched types as errors. This enables you
>   to catch and fix errors as early as possible in the development
>   process.
>
> Type-checking helps you avoid errors when you’re working with
>   different types of values. However, this doesn’t mean that you have to
>   specify the type of every constant and variable that you declare. **If
>   you don’t specify the type of value you need, Swift uses type
>   inference to work out the appropriate type. Type inference enables a
>   compiler to deduce the type of a particular expression automatically
>   when it compiles your code, simply by examining the values you
>   provide.**

Comment: This is perfect , I must have overlooked this while reading the manual ! Appreciate the help , up voted and accepted.